# Join 2 conditions using & operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 queries in pandas and need to join them together.

```
b.loc[b['Speed']=='100.0']

b.loc[b['Month']=='2022-01']
```

I need to join them using & but getting error of unsupported operand type.

Comment: What are the data types of `b['Speed']` and `b['Month']`? You are comparing it with `str` but it should be float and datetime respectively. In That case, you need to compare them accordingly.

Comment: float 64 and period M

Comment: A `float64` value will never equal `'100.0'`.  Remember that `100.0` and `'100.0'` are two very, very different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing your data having different datatype with comparison value of `str`, while it should be float 64 and period M respectively as you have mentioned in your comment.

Try to match your comparison with correct data type. try this:

```
b.loc[(b['Speed'] == 100.0) & (b['Month'] == pd.Period('2022-01'))]
```